# forEach(Main::myMethod); doesn't run the method

Tags: java, class

I try to run the method `setForStatement` in this two lines:

`cu.getNodesByType(ForStmt.class)
.forEach(Main::setForStatement);`

I put hello-String in the different parts of the code to check which parts are works. But the method setForStatement doesn't run, because there are no the line "hello5" on the console:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
import javax.tools.*;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("hello");
    final String fileName = "Class.java";
    final String alteredFileName = "src\\ClassAltered.java";
    CompilationUnit cu;
    try(FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(fileName)){
        cu = JavaParser.parse(in);
    }

    cu.getNodesByType(ForStmt.class)
    .forEach(Main::setForStatement);

    cu.getClassByName("Class").get().setName("ClassAltered");

    try(FileWriter output = new FileWriter(new File(alteredFileName), false)) {
        output.write(cu.toString());
    }

    System.out.println("hello2");
    File[] files = {new File(alteredFileName)};
    String[] options = { "-d", "out//production//Synthesis" };

    System.out.println("hello3");
    JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
    DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject> diagnostics = new DiagnosticCollector<>();
    try (StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(null, null, null)) {
        Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> compilationUnits =
            fileManager.getJavaFileObjectsFromFiles(Arrays.asList(files));
        compiler.getTask(
            null,
            fileManager,
            diagnostics,
            Arrays.asList(options),
            null,
            compilationUnits).call();
        System.out.println("hello4");
        diagnostics.getDiagnostics().forEach(d -> System.out.println(d.getMessage(null)));
    }
}

private static void setForStatement(ForStmt forStmt) {
    System.out.println("hello5");
    MethodCallExpr initializer = (MethodCallExpr) forStmt.getInitialization().get(0);

      SimpleName name = initializer.getName();
      if(!name.toString().equals("FOR")) {

    if (initializer.getArguments().size() == 5
            && initializer.getArgument(0) instanceof NameExpr
            && initializer.getArgument(1) instanceof NameExpr
            && initializer.getArgument(2) instanceof IntegerLiteralExpr
            && initializer.getArgument(3) instanceof CharLiteralExpr
            && initializer.getArgument(4) instanceof CharLiteralExpr) {
        NameExpr a1 = (NameExpr) initializer.getArgument(0);
        NameExpr a2 = (NameExpr) initializer.getArgument(1);
        IntegerLiteralExpr a3 = (IntegerLiteralExpr) initializer.getArgument(2);
        CharLiteralExpr a4 = (CharLiteralExpr) initializer.getArgument(3);
        CharLiteralExpr a5 = (CharLiteralExpr) initializer.getArgument(4);
     }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you would like to post a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using the library from http://javaparser.org/. Correct me if I'm wrong.

The reason that the method `setForStatement(...)` isn't called is simply because `cu.getNodesByType(ForStmt.class)` returns an empty list. You could easily verify this by adding the following line to your code:

`System.out.println("For statements: " + cu.getNodesByType(ForStmt.class).size());`

If you need help figuring out *why* it returns an empty list your really need to provide a [mcve example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).